# Express js find: unexpected result

Tags: mongodb, express

Using Express Js with MongoDB, my query is:

```
assoc.Associations.find({
    $and: [
        { idUser: 'me' }, 
        { $or: [{ stato: '1' }, {$and: [ { idClub: 'myclub' }, { stato: '0' } ] } ] }
        ]
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Error,
            error: err
        })
    }
})
```

i have just one document in my collection and satisfy my requirement:

```
_id : "58459db823b86410e801ac27"
idUser : "me"
idClub : "myclub"
stato : "0"
```

My goal is to perform this condition:

```
idUser = 'me' AND (stato = '1' OR (idClub = 'myclub' and stato = '0'))
```

What's wrong in my find?
Thanks

Comment: The query is fine. I tried it and it works. Are you sure you are not inserting integers instead of strings? Like `0` instead of `'0'`?

Comment: No, all is in place. Now it works. I deleted the collection and recreated and now it finds the results. Dunno what was happens. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
assoc.Associations.find({

        $or: [
          { stato: '1', idUser: 'me' },
          { stato: '0', idClub: 'myclub', idUser: 'me' },
        ]

})
```